# Generate Random int in PHP

Tags: php, random, int

For this question I got answer

```
$a = rand(100000,999999);
```

I am confused which minimum value  variable a can take, it will be 100000 or 100001? I wanted to know is 100000 is included or not?

Comment: Question about `rand()` -> RTM -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 7):

Do a simple test:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    $a = rand(1,4);
    echo $a."<br/>";
}
```

Output (random, but in this case):

```
4
2
4
1
3
3
1
3
3
4
```

So, all numbers are included.

Comment: technically speaking, there's a chance that you NEVER see the boundary values, since they are random numbers...

Comment: Sure. The same applies for any number.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

It clearly says the numbers in the parameters are INCLUSIVE.